# What is the formula or algorithm used to figure out what my data transfer rate

Tags: cbperipheral

I'm currently learning the fundamentals of Technical Supports and one thing has got me confused. I understand 1 byte is equals to 8 bits and to transfer a 1MB file in a second, I need to have an 8Mb per second transfer rate. So my question is how do I figure out what my data transfer rate would be if I'm to transfer a 40MB file? I know its 320Mb per second but I want to know the formula to get to this conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 40MB file (equivalent to 40 x 8= 320Mb), the transfer rate is 40MB/period, where the period is the time needed to do the transfer.
For example, if the period is 4 seconds then 40MB/4 = 10MB/s that is equivalent to 10MB/s x 8 = 80Mb/s